# Is it possible to set my phone where certain contacts will ring when my phone is on silent?

Tags: iphone

I am specifically talking about the Edispatch App. I have an iPhone 5S. I am an NREMT-B in Texas. The county I live in used the app as a back up for our pagers. The app is a necessity. However, I have found that it doesn't go off when my phone is on silent. When it goes off it calls, sends a text, and the app it self sends an alert.

I cannot leave my phone on loud during school and work, because all my text messages and other alerts would be a disturbance to others. However the pager and the app are excused.

I also sent in an App request to the creators of the app for it to override the silent mode if possible, since you know it is an emergency.

Comment: Nope, silent is silent. But you could change the ring tone for all to something very simple and low volume (like single blip). Now go back in and change the ring tone to more profound for the ones you want to disturb you.

Comment: If the app "calls"'your in luck.  You can set up "settings > do not disturb" to allow calls from favorites, the put the phone in do no disturb mode (it on the control center menu - slide up from bottom).  Calls from favorites will get thru.. Others things will all be mute.